# A CMS With Multiple Storage Backends

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was wondering if there was a way to create a CMS which could support many storage backends (MySQL, SQLite, Flat Files, etc) all at the same time in PHP.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Anything else you would like to ask about? Something more specific or this answers your question?

Comment: Was wondering if there is a php class or some resource online to help me along...

Comment: @the_archer, you're gonna a much more than a single class to achieve this. You will need to abstract your data access logic behind interfaces and then implement those interfaces for various data providers you would like to use. Of course each implementation will be specific, for example for SQL you could use an ORM.

Comment: I found this from Drupal website.  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/group/database/6  Thinking about adapting it to my project...

Comment: or this dead project's SQL abstraction layer http://www.toendacms.org/index.php/en/open/about-toendacms.html

Comment: Any other resource you people know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes. You just need to abstract the various APIs for the various backends to create a consistent interface that your application logic can address.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to this is [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Forget being able to use flat files though, it won't support that.